# Spring Boot cannot find controller's mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**DataController**

```
package go.controller;
@Controller
public class DataController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(){
        return "index";
    }
```

**WebMvcConfig**

```
package go.config;
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

**StaticResourceConfiguration**

```
package go.config;
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/**");
    }
}
```

And I have `index.jsp` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/`

Why Spring Boot shows `404 Not found`?

Comment: resource location should be a directory http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistration.html#addResourceLocations-java.lang.String...- , e.g. "/", "classpath:/META-INF/public-web-resources/"

Comment: What package is your main class in? Do you see DataController's mapping logged during startup? Also, as you're using Spring Boot, your configuration is much more verbose than it needs to be. Take a look at [Spring Boot's JSP sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp).